# after_create achievement notification from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am building an achievement system and the final part is notifying the user. Once the achievement is created in the model

```
class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.check_conditions_for(user)
     if user.month_views >= 30 and !user.views_awarded?(self)
      user.award(self)
     end
   end
end
```

I need to flash a custom notice to the user which they can then close. What is the best way to initiate this from the model? I know I can only call Flash messages from the controller but I need a workaround in this instance. It will look very similar to how stack overflow displays their badges.

Comment: When do you plan to `check_conditions_for(user)`? Is this a scheduled job, or does it happen when a user hits a URL?

Comment: It will eventually be a background job but right now it runs each time a media_view is created (a video view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so if a user views a video -- presumably hitting some url, you should just call `Achievement.check_conditions_for(user)` in the associated action. `Achievement.check_conditions_for(user)` can return some value - maybe a notice message - which you can send as a normal flash message. No need for a workaround here if this is just executed when some action is called.

For example, if you have a controller `Videos` and you're calling the action `watch`:

```
def watch
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  @notice = Achievement.check_conditions_for(current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

in app/views/videos/watch.js.erb:

```
alert("<%= @notice %>");
```

Comment: This could work, the only issue is the view is created via an ajax call and there is no redirect. Can I add a flash notice without the redirect?